# Google is displaying the URL path with a duplicated domain name in the search results

Tags: google-index, breadcrumbs, path

URL direction path of our sites displayed by Google in the search results looks a little unusual, it's duplicate somehow as `www.example.com › https://www.example.com +Title`. For example, for "About Us" page (page title: About Us), Google index shows as: `www.example.com › https://www.example.comAbout US`. Please refer to the screenshot (underline in red):

[image]

The normal direction path should be: `www.example.com › About US` or `https://www.example.com › About Us`.

Could anyone advise why this happens? and how to fix the issue?

Comment: here on Google.fr the search query "site:gbsolars.com" returns 6 results (even the about us page) without the bug of the screenshot. Perhaps a temporary google bug.

Comment: thanks for checking. On mobile phone, yes, Google search query returns regular paths, but on desktop, it does display issue results as the screenshot. I tried to search again with IPs in different countries through VPN and found the same issue with desktop query.

Answer (score 1):

While testing the web page in your screenshot in [Google Structured Data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gbsolars.com%2Fabout-us%2F) I found the strange data in your Breadcrumb.

```
https://example.comAboutus
```

Then by checking the source code in the page I can see a strange hidden article inside your Breadcrumb list

```
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" class="trail-item trail-end">
    <span itemprop="item">
        <span itemprop="name">
          <article style="display: none;">https://www.example.com</article>About Us
          </span>
    </span>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2">
</li>
```

So the hidden article which can be seen by robots is seen as a part of the itemprop=name

Remove this article part in your breadcrumb and the problem will be solved.

From Schema.org you should have :

```
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" class="trail-item trail-end">
    <a itemprop="item"  href="https://example.com/about-us/">
        <span itemprop="name">About Us
          </span>
    </a>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2">
</li>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Yes, I recalled that I added the hidden article inside  Breadcrumb list because I got error message (Invalid URL in field "id") of Breadcrumbs in Google SearchCosole. Adding the code did solve the breadcrumb error message but caused another issue. We will remove the hidden article and see how this works.

Comment: Just removed the hidden article, it solved the index issue. However, the Breadcrumb error "The value provided for id must be a valid URL" displays again. Have any ideas on the error as well?

Comment: Yes, you should open a new question for this or find the answer in others but if I can give you a clue, the item prop name should remain **About us** and the id your Url.

Comment: I finally updated my answer with a valid microdata example of your code but i had to add a link instead of the span.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I will open a new question on the URL issue.

Comment: The example code I added to my answer didn't work?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Breadcrumb is controlled by a file named breadcrumbs.php. I opened another question per your suggestion, please refer to the link: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/128189/the-value-provided-for-id-must-be-a-valid-url

Answer (score 0):

You are using breadcrumb schema markup on your pages.  It includes this extra information.  Google is just displaying what you give it.

For example, on your "About Us" page, the breadcrumb markup for the name of the page itself is marked up as:

```
<li itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem" class="trail-item trail-end">
    <span itemprop="item">
        <span itemprop="name">
            <article style="display: none;">
                https://www.example.com
            </article>
            About Us
        </span>
    </span>
    <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
</li>
```

The problem is the `<article style="display: none;">https://www.example.com</article>` in there.   It doesn't display on the site to users because of `style="display: none;"` however Google is picking it up and using it in the breadcrumbs because it is part of the markup. The solution is simply to remove it from your page source code.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen, will do so and check later. Greatly appreciate for your advice :)

Comment: the advice can fix Google index issue, yet it created another issue: Invalid URL in field "id", I will open a question on another issue. Thanks again for your advice.